# Any better way to loop through a collection (struct) in CFML?

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-9, cfml

Please have a look at the code block below:

```
<cfset index = 0 />
<cfloop collection="#anotherPerson#" item="key" >
    <cfset index = index+1 />
    <cfoutput> 
         #key# : #anotherPerson[key]# 
         <cfif index lt ArrayLen(structKeyArray(anotherPerson))> , </cfif>
    </cfoutput>
</cfloop>

<!--- Result 

   age : 24 , haar : Blondes haar , sex : female , ort : Hanau

---->
```

Now can you please tell me how could I achieve the same result without setting an index outside and incrementing it inside the loop? If you notice carefully, I had to write two more **cfset** tag and one **cfif** tag with expensive code just to avoid a **comma (,)** at the end of the collection!

Comment: Can you clarify the overall goal of the code?  Would it be correct to say you want to output each key in the struct followed by the value of said key and delimited each k/v pair with a comma?  Unfortunately, your use of CF9 is going to really limit what you can do.

Comment: Do other versions of CF have better ways to do it?

Comment: Other versions of ColdFusion might have better ways to do things, but the most important factor regarding what version you use, is the version being used wherever you plan to put this into production.

Comment: yes, they have ways to do it with less code.  I will submit an answer now that shows this.  The biggest reason you should leave CF9 though is the growing list of unpatched security vulns that are present.  It's been out of support for years now!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Some friends provided two different solutions. Both are efficient and elegant!

**Solution 1**

```
<cfset isFirst = true />
<cfloop collection="#anotherPerson#" item="key" >
    <cfif isFirst>
        <cfset isFirst = false />
    <cfelse> 
        ,   
    </cfif> 
    <cfoutput> 
       #key# : #anotherPerson[key]# 
    </cfoutput>
</cfloop>
```

**Solution 2**

```
<cfset resultList = "" />
<cfloop collection="#anotherPerson#" item="key" >
    <cfset resultList = ListAppend(resultList, "#key# : #anotherPerson[key]#" ) />
</cfloop>
```

Cheers!

Comment: Solution 1 makes me giggle.

Answer (score 10):

Ok, I'm showing you two answers.  The first will run on ColdFusion 9.  Since other people might find this thread and be using Lucee Server or a newer version of Adobe ColdFusion, I'm including a one-liner that uses higher order functions and runs on ACF 2016.  There's a lot of syntactic sugar (like member functions) and functional programming you're missing by being on CF9.  These answers use script, because manipulating data is not something for a view (where tags/templating are used).

**Set up the data**

```
myStruct = { 'age'=24, 'haar'='Blondes haar', 'sex'='female', 'ort'='Hanau' };
```

**CF9 compat**, convert data to array and use delimiter to add commas

```
myArray = [];
for( key in myStruct ) {
    arrayAppend( myArray, key & ' : ' & myStruct[ key ] );
}
writeOutput( arrayToList( myArray, ', ' ) );
```

**Modern CFML.**  Use struct reduction closure to convert each key into an aggregated array which is then turned into a list.

```
writeOutput( myStruct.reduce( function(r,k,v,s){ return r.append( k & ' : ' & s[ k ] );  }, [] ).toList( ', ' ) );
```

http://cfdocs.org/structreduce

Comment: Modern CFML is often slower, at least in Adobe CF (not sure about Lucee)

Comment: Not to mention if I saw that code I'd delete it and make it readable.

Comment: The OP was concerned about the lines of code used.  (Not something I'd worry about personally, but no matter).  If you're more worried about readability (a noble quest) then the "Modern CFML" example can easily have whitespace introduced and longer variable names. It would be readable to anyone familiar with higher order reduce functions.

Comment: That's shockingly poor code from you, @BradWood. The OP was *not* worried about total lines of code, they had simply observed - correctly, IMO - that they figured that there was probably a way of getting rid of a coupla the lines that seemed suboptimal in their current approach. Downvoting as there's no way this sort of thing should be encouraged. Will remove down vote if you tidy the code up.

Answer (score 0):

Just trim the comma when you are done, no skip logic required.

```
<cfset html = '' />
<cfloop collection="#anotherPerson#" item="key" >
    <cfset html &= "#key# : #anotherPerson[key]# , " />
</cfloop>
<cfset html = left(html,len(html)-3) />

<cfoutput>#html#</cfoutput>
```

Readable, simple, works.

Comment: Yes, it works in most cases.  Though listAppend is a tad simpler, and works even if structure is empty.

Comment: So you are saying to `listAppend(html,"key" : "anotherPerson[key]# ")`

Comment: Yes. Something like that is what they ultimately ended up using.